# Problems with using a for loop with a string from a text file to locate an index in a list of lists

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, python-3.7

I have a text file with a string that has a letter (beginning with "A" that is assigned to a random country). I import that line from the text file to be used with my code where I have a list of countries and rates. I strip the string so that I am left with the country and then I want to be able to locate the country in the string on a list of list that I created. The problem is that when I run my for loop to find the name of the country in the string in the list of lists, where each junior list has the name of the country, GDP and a rate, the for loop runs and can't find the country in the string, even though they are the same type and same spelling. Let me post my code and output below.

When I created the txt file or csv file, this is what I used:

```
f = open("otrasvariables2020.txt", "w")
f.write(str(mis_letras_paises) + "\n")
f.write(str(mis_paises) + "\n")    #(This is the string I need)
f.write(str(mis_poblaciones) + "\n")
f.close()     #to be ready to use it later
```

Let me post some of the output.

```
import linecache

with open("otrasvariables2020.txt") as otras_variables:
    mis_paises = (linecache.getline("otrasvariables2020.txt",2))  

#Here I get the line of text I need, I clean the string and create a
#list with 5 countries.

lista_mis_paises = mis_paises.translate({ord(i): None for i \
                                         in "[]-\'"}).split(", ")
for i in lista_mis_paises:
    if "\n" in i:
        print(i)
        i.replace("\n", "")

for i in lista_mis_paises:
    if len(i) <= 2:
        lista_mis_paises.pop(lista_mis_paises.index(i))
```

Final part of the question: So, ultimately what I want is to find in the array the junior list of the country in the list/string I imported from the text file. Once I locate that junior list I can use the rates and other values there for calculations I need to do. Any ideas what's wrong? The outcome should be the following: Afganistán and other 4 countries should be found in the list of lists, which, for Afganistán, happens to be the 1st item, so I should now be able to create another list of lists but with just the 5 countries instead of the 185 countries I began with.

Comment: Final part of the question:

So, ultimately what I want is to find in the array the junior list of the country in the list/string I imported from the text file. Once I locate that junior list I can use the rates and other values there for calculations I need to do. Any ideas what's wrong?

The outcome should be the following:

Afganistán and other 4 countries should be found in the list of lists, which, for Afganistán, happens to be the 1st item, so I should now be able to create another list of lists but with just the 5 countries instead of the 185 countries I began with.

Comment: I suggest you in order to make clear the question, to add a sample of the file you are reading (at least the format of the lines you are getting) and also will be good to share the expecting results after the code finish. Moreover, I'd suggest you to write the variables in English, which will make easier to non-Spanish people to understood your code.

Comment: This is how it shows in the text file:
[['A-', 'Afganistán'], ['B-', 'Canadá'], ['C-', 'Ruanda'], ['D-', 'El #Salvador'], ['E-', 'República Dominicana']]

I remove the "A", "B", "C"... letters, and keep just the names of the countries in the code you'll see below. Now, for some reason, I get a \n at the end of the last item of the list - regardless, the other items in the list can't be found anyway in the larger list of lists with the countries, GDP, rates values. See more in the next post:

Comment: ['Tailandia', 'Canadá', 'Ruanda', 'El Salvador', 'República #Dominicana\n'] <== SEE, why the \n????
#
#My list of lists look something like this (just a portion of it). By #the way it is a numpy array of 4x185:
#
#['Afganistán' '577.21' '0.9360168799091559' '1.01745744495737']
# ['Albania' '5450.0' '1.1439867079655244' '0.9195410037811979']
....
# ['Zambia' '1430' '0.5473660267181357' '1.380055491126197']
# ['Zimbabue' '1380' '1.4177674974059922' '1.1125312752390342']]

Answer (score 0):

If the concern you have is to strip special characters you don't want to use, I'll do something like that:

```
countries = linecache.getline("otrasvariables2020.txt",2).strip('[]-\'"').rstrip('\n').split(', ')
```

Note: `with open("otrasvariables2020.txt") as otras_variables:` is not used in the code you shared above, so can be removed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, the rstrip() worked to remove the unwanted character "\n". Not sure if that made the difference entirely or not, but it "worked" to the extent that now I can populate my new list with the specific countries that I want. The problem now is that the new list is ordered in alphabetical order and not in the order of occurrence, so in the example above, the order of the junior lists in my list of lists of the selected 5 countries should be:

Afganistán, Canadá, , Ruanda, El Salvador, República Dominicana, 

Instead I have:
Afganistán, Canadá, El Salvador, República Dominicana, Ruanda

Comment: Then you can always order the list using the `sort` methods, right?